# Warning em comparação entre floats como proceder

Tags: c, c++, comparação, ponto-flutuante, warnings

Em um exercício que fiz, é solicitado a fazer um cálculo de juros compostos com **for** para os valores de **5%**, **6%**, **7%**, **8%**, **9%**, e **10%**.

Como eu não poderia utilizar uma verificação por contador sendo o contador um tipo `float`,  e nem usar `switch`, então optei por fazer um teste condicional onde o usuário insere o valor, mas me gera a *warning*:

> warning:comparing floating point with == or != is unsafe [-Wfloat-equal]

Entendo que o motivo do *warning* é pela comparação entre pontos flutuantes ser imprecisa, e pela flag `-Wfloat-equal]` estar ativa, mas ao "rodar" o programa não me é gerado nenhum erro, se essa maneira de realizar a comparação gera um *warning*, qual seria a forma correta de se comparar dois valores do tipo `float`.

Segue o código para avaliação:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::fixed;
using std::setw;
using std::setprecision;
using std::pow;

int main()
{
    //quantia em depósito no fim de cada ano.
    double deposito;
    //quantia inicial antes dos juros.
    double principal = 1000.0;
    //taxa de juros.
    double taxa;
    cout<<"Insira a taxa de juros entre 0.05 á 0.10: ";
    cin>>taxa;
    //exibe cabeçalhos.
    cout << " Ano(s) " << setw(21)<<"Quantidade depositada"<<endl;
    //configura o formato de saída do valo de ponto flutuante.
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    //calcula a quantia de depósito para cada um dos dez anos.
    for( int ano = 1; ano <= 10; ano++ )
    {
        if(taxa == .05)
        {
            //calcula a nova quantia durante o ano especificado
            deposito = principal * pow(1.0 + taxa, ano);
            //exibe o ano e a quantia
            cout << setw(4) << ano << setw(21) << deposito << endl;
        }
        else if(taxa == .06)
        {

            deposito = principal * pow(1.0 + taxa, ano);
            cout << setw(4) << ano << setw(21) << deposito << endl;
        }
        else if(taxa == .07)
        {

            deposito = principal * pow(1.0 + taxa, ano);
            cout << setw(4) << ano << setw(21) << deposito << endl;
        }
        else if(taxa == .08)
        {

            deposito = principal * pow(1.0 + taxa, ano);
            cout << setw(4) << ano << setw(21) << deposito << endl;
        }
        else if(taxa == .09)
        {

            deposito = principal * pow(1.0 + deposito, ano);
            cout << setw(4) << ano << setw(21) << deposito << endl;
        }
        else if(taxa == .10)
        {

            deposito = principal * pow(1.0 + taxa, ano);
            cout << setw(4) << ano << setw(21) << deposito << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            //para que não seja recebido um valor além do especificado.
            cout<<"O valor de taxa inserido é inválido. ";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realmente não dá para fazer uma comparação precisa com ponto flutuante. Se necessita desta precisão use outro tipo. Mas se quiser minimizar o problema, faça uma função que realize uma aproximação. Exemplo:

```
bool isEqual(double x, double y) {
    return std::abs(x - y) <= 1e-5 * std::abs(x);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rUFTbv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kwmxwqhy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Typing/FloatComparing.cpp).

[Fonte](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#floating-point-arith). Note que a aproximação é arbitrária.

Comment: Agora acabei de descobrir o que é **1e-5**  na pagina que você me mandou, se refere a épsilon de máquina, usado especificamente para isso, resposta simples e completa obrigado.

Comment: só pra esclarecer um pouco: o 1e-5 nada mais é do que 10^-5 ou 0.00001. É um valor que, neste contexto, está sendo utilizado pra comparar a diferença absoluta entre x e y. Epsilon é uma letra grega que geralmente tem esse significado. Por isso é comum chamar variáveis que guardam esse valor de Epsilon. (http://math.stackexchange.com/a/176784)