# If não está checando a condição corretamente

Tags: c, if

Estava eu, tentando fazer um programinha bem básico para saber se uma variável tinha ou não uma segunda casa decimal. Porem eu me deparei com um "bug", que ao meu ver é bizarro.

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float f = 1.10;
    float truncado = (f - trunc(f)) * 10;
    printf("Truncado: %f\n", truncado);
    float mod = fmodf(truncado, 1.0f);
    printf("Mod: %f\n", mod);
    if (mod != 0){
        printf("%.2f", f);
    }
    else{
        printf("%.1f", f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Truncado: 1.000000
Mod: 0.000000
1.10
```

Se o programa está apontando que a variável `mod` é igual a zero, porque ele está dando verdadeiro no `if`?

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/PI1xQn).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos fazer o seguinte: mostrar **mais** casas decimais do `mod` e ver se ele é mesmo `0.0`.

Para isso, vou usar a biblioteca `<float.h>` e mudar seu `printf`. A edição está disposta aqui: https://ideone.com/fR3MV0

Observe que seu `float` não é `0.0`.

Para solucionar isso, você pode:

- parsear o `float` para `int` e fazer uma comparação normal ou;
- trabalhar com intervalos, como por ex considerar 0.0 se o número estiver em um intervalo: `-0.00001 < x < 0.00001`

EDIT:

Ah, e o problema de `mod` não exatamente igual a `0.0` não tem a ver com seu código. Tem a ver com a forma que o `float` é guardado na memória, sendo uma potência de 2, com expoente e mantissa inteiros. Mas isso já foge do escopo da pergunta.

Enfim, espero que isso te ajude de alguma forma.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, `if` não retorna nada, ele apenas decide o que fazer baseado na expressão contida nele.

[Número de ponto flutuante não provê exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101), então a igualdade dele ocorre em alguns caso, mas não na maioria. Esse é só um dos motivos porque não pode usá-la para valor monetário.

[Nenhuma solução paliativa é boa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108998/101). O que dá para fazer é normalizar, ou seja, tratar como se fosse ponto fixo fazendo conversão para inteiro de acordo com a escala desejada.

Comment: Exato, conforme sugerido, o correto é usar seu IF desta forma: **if ((int)mod != 0)**, com isso, irás obter o resultado esperado.