# Achar par e o impar em variavel float linguagem C

Tags: c

Está havendo algum erro no meu programa quando eu tento achar o par e o impar de uma variável float.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void exe7(float vet[]){
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        scanf("%f",&vet[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(vet[i] %2 ==0){
            vet[i+5]=vet[i]+0.02;
        }
        if(vet[i] %2 !=0){
            vet[i+5]=vet[i]+0.05;//vet[i+5] pois será armazenado em outra posição;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%f",vet[i]);
    }
}
main(){
    float vet[10];

    exe7(vet);
}
```

Comment: Olha, se isso é um exercício de faculdade, fique sabendo que o(a) professor(a) pode ter alma ou cérebro, mas não as duas coisas. **Paridade é uma propriedade somente dos números inteiros. Números não-inteiros não possuem paridade.**

Answer (score 2):

[Número de ponto flutuante não provê exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101), então a igualdade dele ocorre em alguns caso, mas não na maioria. Esse é só um dos motivos porque não pode usá-la para valor monetário.

[Nenhuma solução paliativa é boa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108998/101). O que dá para fazer é normalizar, ou seja, tratar como se fosse ponto fixo fazendo conversão para inteiro de acordo com a escala desejada.

Créditos: [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219054/if-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-checando-a-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-corretamente)

Uma forma de consertar isso é convertendo o `float` para `int`, mas não sei se será útil na sua situação.

Ou fazer um `if` para checar entre 2 numeros, exemplo:

```
if(vet[i] %2 < 0.0001 && vet[i] %2 > -0.0001){
    vet[i+5]=vet[i]+0.02;//vet[i+5] pois será armazenado em outra posição;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Não dá.

A paridade (a propriedade de ser par ou ímpar) **é exclusiva dos números inteiros**. Variáveis do tipo *float* representam números por aproximação - nunca vão representar um número inteiro, como o Francisco falou.

Se você quiser se aprofundar sobre isso, o Stack de matemática (em inglês) tem explicações sobre [porque paridade não se aplica a números não-inteiros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92451/can-decimal-numbers-be-considered-even-or-odd). A resposta marcada como correta é muito complexa para quem não fez uma faculdade de matemática, mas há respostas mais simples que são igualmente satisfatórias.

O ideal é trabalhar com inteiros, não números de ponto flutuante. Mas se for por esse caminho, melhor do que capturar um número como ponto flutuante e convertê-lo para inteiro é já capturar como inteiro (`%d` ao invés de `%f` no seu `scanf`).

Answer (score -3):

A solução que encontrei foi
a=valor_float;

Se o valor_float for, por exemplo:

2.0000, a vai receber 2

1.5, a vai receber 1

Acho que já resolve