# Por que o std::ceil produz resultados diferentes para float e double?

Tags: c++, matemática, tipagem, c++11

Segue o código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    float calculo = 4.347 * 20 * 100;
    double calculo2 = 4.347 * 20 * 100;
    cout<<std::ceil(calculo)<<std::endl;
    cout<<std::ceil(calculo2)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> Resultado para a variável em float: 8694
> Resultado para a variável em double: 8695
> ```

Alguém pode me explicar porque isso acontece?

O valor para variável em double não deveria ser 8694 também, já que o cálculo resulta em um valor sem casas decimais.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estes tipos não possuem exatidão, então você obtém valores aproximados. Se deseja exatidão não pode usar nenhum dos dois. Quem usa estes tipos de dados deve saber que os valores são aproximados, nunca exatos.

O `ceil()` tem regras de quais valores são considerados para ir para o inteiro acima ou abaixo, com precisão diferente o mesmo número que parece igual na verdade é diferente e você pegou um caso que a precisão maior faz pender mais pro outro lado.

Existe um outro problema. As duas expressões são feitas como `double`. O literal padrão quando tem casa decimal é o `double`, quando quer usar o `float` precisa usar sufixo `f` no número. Então mesmo no primeiro caso toda conta é feita com precisão dupla, e quando vai atribuir ele converte para `float`, o que provoca uma perda. Pra mim uma falha da linguagem, mas que ocorre. Mas não causa o problema apontado, estou colocando como curiosidade.

Se tivesse feito a conta na mão não teria esse erro. Mas o problema mesmo é usar um tipo inexato quando deseja exatidão.

É mais ou menos o mesmo problema da [comparação de valores com ponto flutuantes binário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108998/101) (`float` e `double`) até mesmo do mesmo tipo, o número não é representado exatamente. O mesmo tipo poderia dar diferença dependendo de como se chegou nele.

Há mais detalhes em [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).